# How do I implement a dynamic string matrix?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

```
int i=0, ii=1, j, k, choose=0;
char q='a';
char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char));
words[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)+1);

do {
    printf("you want again(0, 1)\n");
    scanf("%d", &choose);
    j = 0; k = 1;
    do {
        fflush(stdin);
        q = getchar();
        *words[j] = q;
        words[j] = (char *)realloc(words[j], (k+1) * sizeof(char));
        j++; k++;
    } while (q != '\n');
    *words[k] = '\0';
    i++; ii++;
    words = (char**)realloc(words ,ii*sizeof(char));
} while (choose);

puts("pRINT");
int d = 0, t = 0;
for (d = 0; d < i; d++) {
    printf("%s\n", words[d]);
}
```

I need to create a matrix of words, but I don't know the size of each word and how many there will be. That's why I use `malloc` in the beginning and after each iteration `realloc (size+1)`, but after the first iteration, I get a memory error. What did I do wrong and where is the problem?

Comment: Do not cast the return of `malloc`. It is wholly unnecessary. `malloc` returns a *memory address*. It has no *type* (although it is considered `void`). Your allocation should simply be `char **words = malloc (sizeof *words * ii);` and `words[i] = malloc (sizeof **words * ii);` NOTE: it is horribly inefficient to `realloc` for every char read. Allocate some reasonably anticipated number of characters, check the number read against those allocated, and only `realloc` when the limit is reached. Then realloc 2X current, or some other reasonable increase in amount.

Answer (score 2):

While you are free to use *character-oriented* input reading and indexing a character at a time, there are much easier ways to approach this problem. For instance using *line-oriented* input functions (such as `fgets` or `getline`), you can read/store the entire line of data entered by the user at a time.

`getline` has the advantage of allocating sufficient memory to hold each string entered by the user (it is up to you to impose any sanity checks of length). However, if you use `getline`, you need only be concerned with reallocating when your initial number of pointers has been reached. Also, as mentioned in the comment, there is no reason to `realloc` for every input (you can, it is just rather inefficient). You can allocate some reasonable number of pointers and then only `realloc` when that limit is reached.

Below is a short example showing the alternative. Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.  (**note:** rather than stopping the loop on a manually generated `EOF`, you can simply check if `nchr = 1` and automatically exit if the user simply presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> without entering data. It's up to you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NPTR 32

int main (void) {

    char *line = NULL;
    char **words = NULL;
    size_t i, n, idx = 0, nptr = NPTR;
    ssize_t nchr = 0;

    /* initially allocate NPTR pointers */
    if (!(words = malloc (sizeof *words * NPTR))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\nEnter data [ctrl+d] ([crtl+z] on windows) to quit\n\n");

    while (printf (" input ") && (nchr = getline (&line, &n, stdin)) != -1) 
    {   /* for each line read */
        while (nchr && (line[nchr-1] == '\n' || line[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            line[--nchr] = 0;  /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */

        words[idx++] = strdup (line);

        if (idx == nptr) {  /* if limit reached -- realloc */
            void *tmp = realloc (words, 2 * nptr * sizeof *words);
            if (!tmp) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc - memory exhausted.\n");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            words = tmp;
            nptr *= 2;
        }
    }
    free (line);

    printf ("\n\nInput provided by user:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)   /* print strings */
        printf (" words[%2zu] : %s\n", i, words[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)   /* free memory */
        free (words[i]);
    free (words);

    return 0;
}
```

**Usage/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getline_input

Enter data [ctrl+d] ([crtl+z] on windows) to quit

 input my
 input dog
 input has
 input fleas
 input

Input provided by user:

 words[ 0] : my
 words[ 1] : dog
 words[ 2] : has
 words[ 3] : fleas
```

**Exit when user presses [Enter] on Blank Line**

As mentioned above, another easy way to exit the loop when done with input is simply to check that the return for `getline` is greater than `1`. For example, you can replace the initial prompt and the conditional with:

```
printf ("\nEnter data, ([Enter] on blank line to quit)\n\n");

while (printf (" input ") && (nchr = getline (&line, &n, stdin)) > 1)
{ ...
```

I find that more convenient at times.

Comment: Good answer, I found it very usefull. Can you add a note about the use of POSIX standard instead of ANSI? For example to make it compile on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/kt4ROH) I had to add `#include <unistd.h>`.

Comment: Yes, depending on your compiler (and whatever ideaone uses) you may have to include `unistd.h` for getline. With `gcc` `getline` is part of the normal C library since ~2.10. Usually each *man page* will give the POSIX compliance status and when, and if, it has been adopted. Glad you were able to get it working on ideaone.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main mistakes is:

```
char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

and

```
words = (char**)realloc(words ,ii*sizeof(char));
```

You need to change this to

```
char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

and

```
words = (char**)realloc(words ,ii*sizeof(char *));
```

This is because words points to char *.

The second problem is:

```
j = 0; k = 1;
do {
    fflush(stdin);
    q = getchar();
    *words[j] = q;
    words[j] = (char *)realloc(words[j], (k+1) * sizeof(char));
    j++; k++;
} while (q != '\n');
*words[k] = '\0';
```

You need to do this instead:

```
j = 0;k = 1;
do {
    fflush(stdin);
    q = getchar();
    words[i][j] = q;
    j++; k++;
    words[i] = (char *)realloc(words[i], (k+1) * sizeof(char));
} while (q != '\n');
words[i][j] = '\0';
```